# How to record all topics in a rosbag using rosbag API (rosbag::Recorder)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

I am trying to create a recorder logging all topics into a rosbag using [ROSBAG C++ API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API)

The record should be eventually enabled/stopped by some external topic.

The examples show how to log specific topics, but not all of them... Has anyone some insights on how to do this without including the specific message types/headers?

Following [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/216866/rosbag-record-a-in-c/?answer=220364#post-id-220364) I created this first trial, which results in a segmentation fault after the bag is created (bag extension is `.bag.active`).

Am I using `rosbag::Recorder` wrongly here?

```
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/recorder.h>
#include <std_msgs/Bool.h>

std::unique_ptr<rosbag::Recorder> recorder;

void toggle_record(const std_msgs::Bool & msg)
{
    if(msg.data) 
    {
        ROS_INFO("rosbag record -a START!");
        recorder->run();
    }
    else
    {
        ROS_INFO("rosbag record -a FINISH!");
        ros::shutdown();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{   
    ros::init(argc, argv, "joystick_record");    
    rosbag::RecorderOptions options;
    options.record_all = true;    
    options.trigger = false;
    options.regex = false;
    options.do_exclude = true;
    options.quiet = false;
    options.append_date = true;
    options.verbose = false;
    options.buffer_size = 1048576 * 512;
    options.chunk_size = 1024 * 768;
    options.limit = 0; // 0 is unlimited
    options.split = true;
    options.max_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    options.min_space = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    options.min_space_str = "Recording space is running out";
        
    recorder = std::make_unique<rosbag::Recorder>(options);

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber record_sub = nh.subscribe("/record",10, &toggle_record);

    ROS_WARN("Waiting for /record to be true...");

    ros::spin();
}
```

Comment: You want the programmatic equivalent of rosbag record -a (which not only gets all topics when executed, but all new topics that later appear)?  Check out https://answers.ros.org/question/216866/rosbag-record-a-in-c/?answer=220364#post-id-220364 - I've haven't done that recently though so possibly it needs updating.  The `recorder_options_.record_all = true;` is the equivalent of the `-a`.  The include/exclude regex ought to work as well.

Comment: to launch ``rosbag::Recorder`` do you use ``rosbag::Recorder::run`` ?

Comment: Yes, check out https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/tools/rosbag/src/record.cpp#L293-L318 for an example.  `run()` blocks so you need to work around that.

Comment: The main issue is that ``recorder.run()`` already spins internally, and I should also spin in my node to check whether to shutdown the node... @LucasWalter any insights? Thank you so much

Comment: I solved this by using https://github.com/joshs333/bag_recorder package. It's full featured and can be triggered externally by other nodes.

Comment: Does shutting down the node and having it respawn automatically work for you?  It's not ideal but that's where I stopped.  But now that I look it could be possible to modify that run method, the blocking problem is caused by the `join()` here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp#L247 - a modified Recorder run() could return without calling join and also modify the doRecord while loop to exit gracefully when a stop is indicated (instead of exiting only on node shutdowns and a few other conditions)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue temporarily by using the [bag_recorder](https://github.com/joshs333/bag_recorder) package.
It's well documented, fully featured and can be triggered externally by other nodes.

Still, looking for help on a simpler solution with `rosbag::Recorder`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to start the `rosbag` via [`rosmon`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmon) rosservice call. Then your C++ Node would only need to make the service call to start or stop it.